# Scala.js - How to convert ArrayBuffer to Array[Byte]?

Tags: scala.js

DOM API returns `ArrayBuffer` but what I need is `Array[Byte]`. How can I do a conversion?

```scala
import scala.scalajs.js.typedarray.ArrayBuffer

def toScalaArray(input: ArrayBuffer): Array[Byte] = {
  // code in question
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in an `Int8Array`, then call the extension method `.toArray` defined in the `typedarray` package:

```scala
import scala.scalajs.js.typedarray._

def toScalaArray(input: ArrayBuffer): Array[Byte] =
  new Int8Array(input).toArray
```